# Rails: rake db:create:all fails to connect to PostgreSQL database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, postgresql-9.1, rails-postgresql

I am trying to create a Rails app that uses PostgreSQL. Here is a description of what I did.

---

**PostgreSQL setup:**
I installed PostgreSQL 9.1.3 via the [ppa:pitti/postgresql](https://launchpad.net/~pitti/+archive/postgresql) maintained by Martin Pitt. There was PostgreSQL  8.4 installed before; I am not sure if it is still installed or gone.

- I added a database user with superuser rights to the database that has the same name as my Ubuntu account.
- I start the database daemon with `sudo service postgresql start`.
- I installed [pgadmin3, Version 1.14.0 Beta 1](http://pgadmin.org) via [ppa:rhonda/pgadmin3](https://launchpad.net/~rhonda/+archive/pgadmin3) maintained by Gerfried Fuchs.
- I can connect via pgadmin3 using my user account and password and port 5433.

My postgres configuration in *pg_hba.conf* is as follows (removed comments for readability).

```
[...]
local   all             postgres                                peer
local   all             all                                     peer
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

---

**Rails setup:**
Now I want to create a Rails application that uses PostgreSQL.

- I installed Ruby 1.9.3-p125 via RVM.
- I installed Rails 3.2.3 into the Gemset ruby-1.9.3-p125@global.
- I created a .rvmrc and Gemset for the application.
- I created a Rails application via `rails new my_test_app -d postgresql`.
- I configured the `user` name and `password` in *config/database.yml* for *development* and *test* and removed *production*.
- I configured `host: localhost` and `port: 5433` in *config/database.yml*.

Here is the content of my *config/database.yml* (removed comments for readability).

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: my_test_app_development
  pool: 5
  username: johndoe
  password: password    
  host: localhost
  port: 5433

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: my_test_app_test
  pool: 5
  username: johndoe
  password: password
```

---

**Problem:**
However, when I run `bundle exec rake db:create:all` I receive the following error message.

```
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket
"/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
[...]
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "encoding"=>"unicode",
"database"=>"my_test_app_test", "pool"=>5, "username"=>"johndoe",
"password"=>"password"}
```

---

**Question:**
Why is the port different to the one I use when I successfully connect via pgadmin3?

Comment: Rails app tries to connect through UNIX socket instead of TCP socket localhost:5433. It mustn't behave so if you setup database.yml properly. Check contents of database.yml and ensure that rails does read this file. Please provide contents of database.yml. You also can try to use different adapter (sqlite, for example) to test if your settings applies.

Comment: Does that mean I should not use port 5433 but 5432 which was in *database.yml* as a uncommented line?

Comment: For are those who install PG via Homebrew and are having problems, I found another answer. Just uninstall pg gem and reinstall with Homebrew configs. See the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/19609228/1072058.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

@Riateche: Finally, I saw that the database configuration for *test* environment misses the explicit settings for **host** and **port**. After I added the settings to the *test* environment, I was able to run the command `bundle exec rake db:create:all` successfully.
I must say, I do not like that they suggest those settings for the *development* enviroment, but did not add them for the other environments. That makes it very likely to miss them, as I proofed.

```
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: my_test_app_test
  pool: 5
  username: johndoe
  password: password
  host: localhost
  port: 5433
```

Comment: is the port number is same to all pc? if no,how can I know my port number?

Comment: @AmySukumunu You can configure the **port** in the configuration file which you can find here: `/etc/postgresql/<VERSION>/main/postgresql.conf`. More infos [here](http://ubuntumanual.org/posts/505/how-to-install-postgresql-on-ubuntu). The default port is 5432 as far as I know.

Comment: in my case I needed adding just `host`

Comment: Hi you guys are using Linux OS ? What if i'm doing my rails project in windows base ? where can i find that etc directory

Comment: If you configure it through ```/etc/postgresql/<VERSION>/main/postgresql.conf``` you are not able to maintain multiple postresql databases in your computer.

Comment: @Katarzyna Where would I apply the configuration **per database** instead?

Comment: You can find it in gist: https://gist.github.com/siwka/64c26f60dfe577a0fe2d5a384cbfe8fe

Answer (score 1):

If any *psql* client session is accessing  *template1*  ( for example *psql* or *pgAdmin* ), 
`rake db:migrate`  fails. Close any sessions  before doing  `rake db:migrate` .

Answer (score 1):

you can change your postgresql configuration in pg_hba.conf to trust.

```
[...]
local   all             postgres                                peer
local   all             all                                     trust
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I solve it by running this solution

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
```