# Rails: rake db:create:all (could not connect to server)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rails-migrations, rails-postgresql

follow the screencasts http://railscasts.com/episodes/342-migrating-to-postgresql?autoplay=true 
up to the steps of **"rake db:create:all"** and get error:

> could not connect to server: No such file or directory    Is the server
>   running locally and accepting     connections on Unix domain socket
>   "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

refer the question on [Rails: rake db:create:all fails to connect to PostgreSQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263821/rails-rake-dbcreateall-fails-to-connect-to-postgresql-database)

but still unable to resolve it. Not sure what is the problem.
[image]

[database.yml]

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: store_development
  pool: 5
  username: amysukumunu 
  password:
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: store_test
  pool: 5
  username: amysukumunu
  password:
```

Answer (score 4):

**[update2]**

okay, This is what you should do:

1. the unix socket should be at `/var/pgsql_socket`(as per the plist image) where as rails is trying to find the socket file in `/tmp`. I believe this is the reason for error. so Edit your `database.yml` & explicitly add socket location. so your final database.yml should look like [this](https://gist.github.com/2700597). change the file location for your unix socket location. try to connection now?

2) If it still doesn't connect. verify that postgres server is actually running

```
$ netstat -a | grep postgre
```

if its running, try connecting to it from terminal using `psql` command. incase its, not running. try starting it manually

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
```

If it still doesn't start, 
Are there any error messages in the server.log? If yes do post them here.

Good luck!
=======UPDATED===============
[image]
[image]

Comment: it my finder don't have the file "postgresql.conf". 0items.
what is the template1 means? id it my app name?

Comment: template1 is the default database on postgressql but it looks like its different on mac(no postgresql.conf?), so try following the updated troubleshooting instructions.

Comment: it's say dont have "org.postgresql.postgres.plist" on the second command

Comment: Well, you can try listing all files `ls -R /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/`  & see if plist is present. if yes, then try to copy that plist to `~/Library/LaunchAgents` & then, proceed to next command. Hope it helps

Comment: I updated the image of the plist I find online and copy it into launchAgents and execute the second command but get "cp: /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.0.1/org.postgresql.postgres.plist: No such file or directory
"

Comment: Alright, I have updated my answer. try it, see if it works for you

Comment: Thanks... It shows "server starting." Is this means it finally ok?

Comment: Yes, It Should be. are you still not able to connect?