# Rails: rake db:create:all (could not connect to server) psql works fine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-postgresql

I've looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10482853/rails-rake-dbcreateall-could-not-connect-to-server) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263821/rails-rake-dbcreateall-fails-to-connect-to-postgresql-database) but still can't solve my problem. 
I have my setup working perfectly on my normal linux but when I tried to recreate it on my mac postgres won't work with rails. After following [these](http://railscasts.com/episodes/342-migrating-to-postgresql?view=asciicast) instructions from railscasts I get to the point where I run rake:db:create:all

running rake db:create:all:

```
$ rake db:create:all                                                                 -- 
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

but running psql works fine:

```
$ psql
psql (9.3.1)
Type "help" for help.

crashandburn4=#
```

checking which port postgres is running on yields:

```
$ cat /etc/services |grep post
postgresql      5432/udp    # PostgreSQL Database
postgresql      5432/tcp    # PostgreSQL Database
```

so it doesn't appear to be an incorrect port and my database.yml explicitely states the port:

```
# database.yml
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: blog_development
  pool: 5
  username: myusername
  password:
  port: 5432

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: blog_test
  pool: 5
  username: myusername
  password:
  port: 5432


production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: blog_production
  pool: 5
  username: myusername
  password:
  port: 5432
```

running netstat also looks fine (I think):

```
$ netstat -a | grep postgre
tcp6       0      0  localhost.postgres     *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  localhost.postgresql   *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0  localhost.postgres     *.*                    LISTEN
```

which is about everything I could come up with to try and diagnose the problem other than calling a witchdocter :) anyone got any ideas?

EDIT: Solved my question (good old rubber duck debugging) figured I'd post anyway to help any other poor souls that spend an hour digging through and double checking config-files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incorrect config, this was fixed by including the hostname with the configuration (see below), one interesting note is that this is only necessary for the macbook pro that I'm running on and does not occur on the Linux box I use.

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: blog_development
  pool: 5
  username: myusername
  password:
  host: localhost
  port: 5432

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: blog_test
  pool: 5
  username: myusername
  password:
  host: localhost
  port: 5432


production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: blog_production
  pool: 5
  username: myusername
  password:
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
```