# In Rails, Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql",

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I'm trying to run `rake db:create` or `rake db:setup` but I get the following error. It's strange because `rake db:create` it's working fine from others folders with other Rails projects.

```
user:project user$ rake db:create
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/pgsql_socket/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-    3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:991:in `initialize'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-    3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:991:in `new'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:991:in `connect'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:260:in `initialize'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:27:in `new'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:27:in `postgresql_connection'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-    3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:304:in     `new_connection'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:323:in `checkout_new_connection'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-    3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:265:in `block (2     levels) in checkout'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-    3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:261:in `loop'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:261:in `block in checkout'
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:260:in `checkout'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:162:in `connection'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:409:in     `retrieve_connection'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:107:in `retrieve_connection'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:89:in `connection'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:110:in `rescue in create_database'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.1.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:54:in `create_database'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-    3.1.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:42:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/rake:19:in `<main>'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql", "database"=>"project_test",     "username"=>nil, "password"=>nil, "min_messages"=>"warning"}
```

This is my `database.yml`

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: project_development
  username:
  password:
  min_messages: warning

test:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: project_test
  username:
  password:
  min_messages: warning

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: project_production
  username:
  password:
  min_messages: warning
```

Posgree is insatelled on `/usr/local/var/postgres`. Shouldn't rake try to look it in the same folder instead of `/var/pgsql_socket/` ?  (I don't have a /usr/local/var/pgsql_socket anyways)

Comment: This is complaining about the postgres server not running. Is it? Is it setup to listen on the socket your app is trying to connect to?

Comment: But the server is running, is only complaining about this particular project. The socket is not set on database.sql. All is set as default.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410686/postgres-could-not-connect-to-server http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13538593/installing-postgresql-with-homebrew-and-rails-on-mountain-lion?lq=1

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Solved!

Solution was simple to update current installed gems.

Another solution to try is set `host: localhost` or whatever host you use on development settings on database.yml file.

Comment: which ones? what was the actual process? 

I ran into the same errors with same problem but your vague comment is not helping at all.

Comment: Try adding `host: localhost` or whatever host you use on your database.yml file

Comment: `host: localhost` is what I was missing

Answer (score 8):

I installed PG on Mac OS X via Homebrew (I didn't realize it came default in Mac OS X), and had the same problem. I may have made the problem worse by installing the pg gem before installing pg via Homebrew.

I solved this same problem by doing the following:

1. Make sure that all binaries are pointing to binaries in Cellar directory (/usr/local/Cellar on Mac OS X)
2. Uninstall pg gem `gem uninstall pg`
3. Reinstall with Homebrew configs `gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config` (if you created a rails project with pg setup, this is explained in your database.yml config file)

And it worked!

Answer (score 6):

First, you will need to create your user manually in Postgres, while granting privilege of database creation (AKA createdb) for this user.

To do so, first, open Postgres shell prompt

`$ sudo -u postgres psql`

Create your user

`postgres=# create role Your_DB_username with createdb login password 'YOUR_PASSWORD';`

Exit from Postgres shell

`postgres=# \q`

Do whatever db-related rake task:

`$ rake db:create`

And it will work!

Answer (score 4):

The answer from zquintana above worked for me with a few small caveats.

My solution (using Homebrew):

1. If you have the gem installed `gem uninstall pg`
2. Remove old copy of postgresql `brew uninstall postgresql`
3. Re-install postgresql `brew install postgresql`
4. The install notes mention:

> To have launchd start postgresql at login:
>
> > `ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/postgresql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents`
>
> Then to load postgresql now:
>
> > `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist`
>
> Or, if you don't want/need launchctl, you can just run:
>
> > `postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres`

4. So run `ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/postgresql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents`
5. Then `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist`
6. Now re-install the gem with the Homebrew configs `gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config`
7. Now run your `rake db:create`

Answer (score 4):

In my case this was all I needed: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/75221

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
```

Answer (score 2):

I encountered an identical issue and was able to solve the error by:

1. using postgresapp.com (recommended by heroku in https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#local-setup),
2. adding to config/database.yml

   ```
   host: localhost
   ```
3. resetting shared memory settings as recommended in troubleshooting section of http://postgresapp.com/documentation:

   ```
   sudo sysctl -w kern.sysv.shmall=65536
   sudo sysctl -w kern.sysv.shmmax=16777216
   ```

Comment: Can you add the full code to show where you added the local host. it would really help people that are landing on this question and curious.

Comment: Isn't development the only environment you'd connect to localhost in?

Answer (score 1):

Also check you don't have an open connection such as a client or an application connected to the instance. If that happen you will see this in the error

```
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"xxxx", "database"=>"xxxx", "host"=>"localhost", "username"=>"postgres", "password"=>"xxxxx", "pool"=>5, "timeout"=>5000}
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::ObjectInUse: ERROR:  source database "template1" is being accessed by other users
DETAIL:  There is 1 other session using the database.
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple add `host: localhost` to your database.yml

For more detail please visit [rake db:create:all fails to connect to PostgreSQL database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263821/rails-rake-dbcreateall-fails-to-connect-to-postgresql-database)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by making sure that the name of my database in the database.yml file was in the following format: appname_development, appname_test, and appname_production. Here is my database.yml file as an example:

```
    development:
      adapter: postgresql
      database: parallax_development
      username:
      password:

    test:
      adapter: postgresql
      database: parallax_test
      username:
      password:

    production:
      adapter: postgresql
      database: parallax_production
      username:
      password:
```