# How to upgrade PostgreSQL from version 9.6 to version 10.1 without losing data?

Tags: postgresql, upgrade

I'm using the PostgreSQL database for my Ruby on Rails application (on Mac OS X 10.9).

Are there any detailed instructions on how to upgrade PostgreSQL database?

I'm afraid I will destroy the data in the database or mess it up.

Comment: Do backups in any case.

Answer (score 419, accepted):

Assuming you've used home-brew to install and upgrade Postgres, you can perform the following steps.

1. Stop current Postgres server:

   `launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist`
2. Initialize a new 10.1 database:

   `initdb /usr/local/var/postgres10.1 -E utf8`
3. run `pg_upgrade` *(note: change bin version if you're upgrading from something other than below)*:

   ```
   pg_upgrade -v \
       -d /usr/local/var/postgres \
       -D /usr/local/var/postgres10.1 \
       -b /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.6.5/bin/ \
       -B /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/10.1/bin/
   ```

   `-v` to enable verbose internal logging

   `-d` the old database cluster configuration directory

   `-D` the new database cluster configuration directory

   `-b` the old PostgreSQL executable directory

   `-B` the new PostgreSQL executable directory
4. Move new data into place:

   ```
   cd /usr/local/var
   mv postgres postgres9.6
   mv postgres10.1 postgres
   ```
5. Restart Postgres:

   `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist`
6. Check `/usr/local/var/postgres/server.log` for details and to make sure the new server started properly.
7. Finally, re-install the rails `pg` gem

   ```
   gem uninstall pg
   gem install pg
   ```

I suggest you take some time to read the [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/upgrading.html) to understand exactly what you're doing in the above steps to minimize frustrations.

Comment: I hade to use the following command to initialize the database: `initdb /usr/local/var/postgres9.4 -E utf8 --lc-collate=C --lc-ctype=utf-8 --lc-monetary=C --lc-numeric=C`

Comment: It follow your guide step by step. And everything worked! Thank you so much.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you very much. I was already afraid this would take me 2-3 hours to finish. But it took less than 5 minutes and I could continue programming. Kudos.

Comment: Works great, thank you!
I was getting an error about postgres missing pg_tblspc which is guess is common for Yosemite, but i was able to fix it with:

`mkdir /usr/local/var/postgres/pg_tblspc`
`mkdir /usr/local/var/postgres/pg_twophase`
`mkdir /usr/local/var/postgres/pg_stat_tmp`

Comment: Be careful with the `delete_old_cluster.sh` command. I had first manually deleted the /usr/local/postgres9.3 directories, than ran this command and it seems I lost the entire /usr/local/var/postgres directory (I was able to restore it from Time Machine)

Comment: After you reinstall your pg gem, you might need to do $ bundle update pg to keep your Gemfile.lock in sync.

Comment: If you're using Bundler, you should remove the gem using `gem uninstall pg` but then let bundler reinstall the correct version from Gemfile.lock by simply running `bundle`.

Comment: Wonderful stuff. Worth noting that if you're getting `~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist: No such file or directory` then this [Thoughtbot post](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/starting-and-stopping-background-services-with-homebrew) will help.

Comment: Can you help me to do it on Ubuntu

Comment: @pramod it should be roughly the same steps, just replace the OS X specifics with those for Ubuntu; primarily steps 1 & 5, and the file paths.

Comment: Step 4. Move new data into place:
...
I must be missing something; how do I move old data into the upgraded db?

Comment: `--link` might be quite useful if you don't want to copy data.

Comment: worked great for update from 9.4.0 to 9.5.4, although had to adjust the folder names (obviously).

Comment: I had to change the trust mode in pg_hba.conf for both (9.4 and 9.6 in my case) to "trust".

Comment: This recipe assumes your database was initialized with utf8.   If not you may get an error like: encodings for database "postgres" do not match:  old "SQL_ASCII", new "UTF8"

Comment: Minor update: `brew` now also has the option to use `brew services stop postgresql` and `brew services start postgresql` instead of directly calling `launchctl unload` and `launchctl load`.

Comment: If sh** hits the fan, you can also try following https://gist.github.com/chbrown/647a54dc3e1c2e8c7395.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48512480/719276) worked for me and is really simple ; I don't know if your answer is outdated or does something different. If it is out of date, could you update it?

Comment: Yeah, this answer was originally written to upgrade between 7 and 8 (I believe), and at that time they did not have an automated way to upgrade the database. I agree that the homebrew upgrade script would be the current "best" answer. That said, this method still works even if it's not the "easiest" anymore.

Answer (score 71):

Despite all answers above, here goes my 5 cents.

It works on any OS and from any-to-any postgres version.

- Stop any running postgres instance;
- Install the new version and start it; Check if you can connect to the new version as well;
- Change old version's `postgresql.conf` -> `port` from `5432` to `5433`;
- Start the old version postgres instance;
- Open a terminal and `cd` to the new version `bin` folder;
- Run `pg_dumpall -p 5433 -U <username> | psql -p 5432 -U <username>`
- Stop old postgres running instance;

Comment: Thanks Christian, this is definately a great and easy solution, I successfully went from 9.3 to 9.5 like this

Comment: Worked beautifully for upgrading from 9.1 to 9.5 on a Windows 2012 server.

Comment: A problem of this solution is that if you had changed some Postgres config files (eg. `postgresql.conf` or `pg_hba.conf`) you would need to manually replicate those changes in the new installation. Instead, if you use `pg_upgradecluster`, config files get copied to the new cluster: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/pg_upgradecluster.8.html

Comment: Note that right after you'll start the command you will get _one_ password prompt, but you have to enter 2 passwords one by one confirming each by Enter. Or you'll get `pg_dumpall: could not connect to database "XXX": fe_sendauth: no password supplied`

Comment: @Lu55 you can also setup `trust` in the origin database configuration to avoid having to input passwords. Btw, this method worked wonders to migrate 9.4 to 9.6 in my case.

Comment: Technically this won't work for any-to-any version, just for source versions at or above 7.0, as the manual states: `Current releases of the dump programs can read data from any server version back to 7.0.`

Comment: @Alphaaa `pb_upgradecluster` is an Ubuntu-only util, op asked about OS X.

Comment: How exactly do you start a secondary instance when the primary one runs using `systemctl`, and how to you swap those afterwards ?

Comment: Is there an easier way to do this on Windows 10?  I installed postgreSql 15 like 6 months ago, haven't used it yet (other than to create and store passwords, etc in a vault).  I intend to use it now.  Just want to upgrade to the latest minor release (15.3) without having to reinstall or go thru that much before I start doing major work in there.

Answer (score 59):

Here is the solution for **Ubuntu** users

First we have to stop postgresql

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql stop
```

Create a new file called /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list and add below line

```
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ utopic-pgdg main
```

Follow below commands

```
wget -q -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.4
sudo pg_dropcluster --stop 9.4 main 
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql start
```

Now we have everything, just need to upgrade it as below

```
sudo pg_upgradecluster 9.3 main
sudo pg_dropcluster 9.3 main
```

That's it. Mostly upgraded cluster will run on port number 5433. Check it with below command

```
sudo pg_lsclusters
```

Comment: The second to last sentence where you say "Mostly upgraded cluster will run on port number 5433" should probably say "The 9.3 cluster will be running on port number 5433 so that you can revert if necessary".

Comment: Note: For ubuntu 14.04 use "trusty-pgdb" instead of utopic-pgdb

Comment: Note that this does **NOT** do an in-place upgrade. it's therefore completely useless for my 700 GB DB on a 1TB volume.

Comment: I know this post is really old I am trying to go from 9.6 to 12 will this work with making such a large jump? I am also wondering if it is focal instead of utopic?

Answer (score 27):

If you are using homebrew and homebrew services, you can probably just do:

```
brew services stop postgresql
brew upgrade postgresql
brew postgresql-upgrade-database
brew services start postgresql
```

I think this might not work completely if you are using advanced postgres features, but it worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Worked perfectly for macOS Mojave 10.14.2 - Thanks!

Comment: Still working in 2021 on OS Catalina 10.15.7

Answer (score 18):

**Update**: This process is the same for upgrading 9.5 through at least 11.5; simply modify the commands to reflect versions `9.6` and `10`, where `9.6` is the *old* version and `10` is the *new* version. Be sure to adjust the "old" and "new" directories accordingly, too.

---

I just upgraded PostgreSQL 9.5 to 9.6 on Ubuntu and thought I'd share my findings, as there are a couple of OS/package-specific nuances of which to be aware.

(**I didn't want to have to dump and restore data manually**, so several of the other answers here were not viable.)

In short, the process consists of installing the new version of PostgreSQL alongside the old version (e.g., 9.5 and 9.6), and then running the `pg_upgrade` binary, which is explained in (some) detail at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/pgupgrade.html .

The only "tricky" aspect of `pg_upgrade` is that failure to pass the correct value for an argument, or failure to be logged-in as the correct user or `cd` to the correct location before executing a command, may lead to cryptic error messages.

On Ubuntu (and probably Debian), provided you are using the "official" repo, `deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ xenial-pgdg main`, and provided you haven't changed the default filesystem paths or runtime options, the following procedure should do the job.

Install the new version (note that we specify the `9.6`, explicitly):

```
sudo apt install postgresql-9.6
```

Once installation succeeds, both versions will be running side-by-side, but on different ports. The installation output mentions this, at the bottom, but it's easy to overlook:

```
Creating new cluster 9.6/main ...
  config /etc/postgresql/9.6/main
  data   /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main
  locale en_US.UTF-8
  socket /var/run/postgresql
  port   5433
```

Stop both server instances (this will stop both at the same time):

```
sudo systemctl stop postgresql
```

Switch to the dedicated PostgreSQL system user:

```
su postgres
```

Move into his home directory (failure to do this will cause errors):

```
cd ~
```

`pg_upgrade` *requires* the following inputs (`pg_upgrade --help` tells us this):

```
When you run pg_upgrade, you must provide the following information:
  the data directory for the old cluster  (-d DATADIR)
  the data directory for the new cluster  (-D DATADIR)
  the "bin" directory for the old version (-b BINDIR)
  the "bin" directory for the new version (-B BINDIR)
```

These inputs may be specified with "long names", to make them easier to visualize:

```
  -b, --old-bindir=BINDIR       old cluster executable directory
  -B, --new-bindir=BINDIR       new cluster executable directory
  -d, --old-datadir=DATADIR     old cluster data directory
  -D, --new-datadir=DATADIR     new cluster data directory
```

We must also pass the `--new-options` switch, because failure to do so results in the following:

```
connection to database failed: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/lib/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.50432"?
```

This occurs because the default configuration options are applied in the absence of this switch, which results in incorrect connection options being used, hence the socket error.

Execute the `pg_upgrade` command from the *new* PostgreSQL version:

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin/pg_upgrade --old-bindir=/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin --new-bindir=/usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin --old-datadir=/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main --new-datadir=/var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main --old-options=-cconfig_file=/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf --new-options=-cconfig_file=/etc/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf
```

Logout of the dedicated system user account:

```
exit
```

The upgrade is now complete, *but*, the new instance will bind to port `5433` (the standard default is `5432`), so keep this in mind if attempting to test the new instance before "cutting-over" to it.

Start the server as normal (again, this will start both the old and new instances):

```
systemctl start postgresql
```

If you want to make the new version the default, you will need to edit the effective configuration file, e.g., `/etc/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf`, and ensure that the port is defined as such:

```
port = 5432
```

If you do this, either change the old version's port number to `5433` at the same time (before starting the services), or, simply remove the old version (this will *not* remove your actual database content; you would need to use `apt --purge remove postgresql-9.5` for that to happen):

```
apt remove postgresql-9.5
```

The above command will stop all instances, so you'll need to start the new instance one last time with:

```
systemctl start postgresql
```

As a final point of note, don't forget to consider `pg_upgrade`'s good advice:

```
Upgrade Complete
----------------
Optimizer statistics are not transferred by pg_upgrade so,
once you start the new server, consider running:
    ./analyze_new_cluster.sh

Running this script will delete the old cluster's data files:
    ./delete_old_cluster.sh
```

Comment: For me in Mac Yosemite, PostgreSQL 9.2 -> 9.5: `sudo su postgres`, change all METHOD in both installation's pg_hba.conf to trust before pg_upgrade, running pg_upgrade in /private/tmp not ~ didn't work so `sudo mkdir /foobar` with `chmod 777 /foobar` and ran it there. At last the pg_upgrade command: `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin/pg_upgrade -b /Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/bin -B /Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin -d /Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/data -D /Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/data -o -cconfig_file=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.2/data/postgresql.conf -O -cconfig_file=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.5/data/postgresql.conf`

Comment: i was able to upgrade successfully from 9.5 to 11.5 had to add postgres apt repositories to ubuntu. and then just follow those steps : https://tecadmin.net/install-postgresql-server-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score 13):

The [user manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/upgrading.html) covers this topic in depth. You can:

- `pg_upgrade` in-place; or
- `pg_dump` and `pg_restore`.

If in doubt, do it with dumps. Don't delete the old data directory, just keep it in case something goes wrong / you make a mistake; that way you can just go back to your unchanged 9.3 install.

For details, see the manual.

If you're stuck, post a detailed question explaining how you're stuck, where, and what you tried first. It depends a bit on how you installed PostgreSQL too, as there are several different "distributions" of PostgreSQL for OS X (unfortunately). So you'd need to provide that info.

Answer (score 8):

Standing on the shoulders of the other poor creatures trodding through this muck, I was able to follow these steps to get back up and running after an upgrade to Yosemite:

Assuming you've used home-brew to install and upgrade Postgres, you can perform the following steps.

1. Stop current Postgres server:

   `launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist`
2. Initialize a new 9.4 database:

   `initdb /usr/local/var/postgres9.4 -E utf8`
3. Install postgres 9.3 (as it was no longer present on my machine):

   `brew install homebrew/versions/postgresql93`
4. Add directories removed during Yosemite upgrade:

   `mkdir -p /usr/local/var/postgres/{pg_tblspc,pg_twophase,pg_stat_tmp}/touch /usr/local/var/postgres/{pg_tblspc,pg_twophase,pg_stat_tmp}/.keep`
5. run `pg_upgrade`:

   `pg_upgrade -v -d /usr/local/var/postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres9.4 -b /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql93/9.3.5/bin/ -B /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.0/bin/`
6. Move new data into place:

   ```
   cd /usr/local/var
   mv postgres postgres9.3
   mv postgres9.4 postgres
   ```
7. Restart Postgres:

   `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist`
8. Check `/usr/local/var/postgres/server.log` for details and to make sure the new server started properly.
9. Finally, re-install related libraries?

   ```
   pip install --upgrade psycopg2
   gem uninstall pg
   gem install pg
   ```

Comment: pg_upgrade -v -d /usr/local/var/postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres9.4 -b /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql93/9.3.*/bin/ -B /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.4.*/bin/  # Minor versions might be different.

Comment: Thanks for this. I accidentally ran `brew cleanup` before migrating data and that caused postgres9.3 to be uninstalled. This helped. :)

Answer (score 7):

Looks like the solution has been baked into Homebrew now:

```
$ brew info postgresql
...
==> Caveats
To migrate existing data from a previous major version of PostgreSQL run:
  brew postgresql-upgrade-database
....
```

Answer (score 2):

On **Windows** I kept facing different errors messages when trying to use `pg_upgrade`.

Saved a lot of time for me to just:

1. Backup DB
2. Uninstall all copies of PostgreSQL
3. Install 9.5
4. Restore DB

Comment: Did this for 9.5 to 9.6 and worked perfectly as well.  Good to be able to do easy exact upgrade as well, rather than "latest".  I used Big SQL to get the right installer (https://www.openscg.com/bigsql/postgresql/installers.jsp/).

Answer (score 1):

This did it for me.

https://gist.github.com/dideler/60c9ce184198666e5ab4

Short and to the point. I honestly don't aim to understand the guts of PostgreSQL, I want to get stuff done.

Comment: This uses Ubuntu's pg_upgradecluster tool which can be much slower than PostgreSQL's pg_upgrade tool and of course is only available on Ubuntu.

Comment: @alfonx Not true. I have it on my Debian `jessie`. Had 10+ DBs and an amount of ~400MB of database data was converted in a blink of an eye. Then again, I am using a virtual Debian on an SSD.

Comment: Let me correct myself: pg_upgradecluster is part of "Debian PostgreSQL infrastructure", so only available on Debian-based distros. About the speed pg_upgrade offers the "--link" option, which linking not copying data where possible: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/pgupgrade.html

Comment: Perhaps we aim for different outcomes. After a distro-wide software upgrade I ended up with 2 version of PostgreSQL and the data my projects used was stuck on the older version (9.3). So I just hunted down the link above (in my answer) and upgraded it, got rid of the old "cluster" and the older PG version.

Comment: I tried to upgrade from 9.4 to 11 with `pg_upgradecluster 9.4 main` but I get the error Error: `specified cluster does not exist` ... I guess, I have to install postgresql-9.4 again first with this guide: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt#Quickstart

Answer (score 1):

My solution for upgrading from Postgresql 11 to Postgresql 12 on Windows 10 is the following.

As a first remark you will need to be able stop and start the Postgresql service. You can do this by the following commands in Powershell.

Start: 
`pg_ctl start -D “d:\postgresql\11\data”`

Stop:
`pg_ctl stop -D “d:\postgresql\11\data”`

Status: 
`pg_ctl status -D “d:\postgresql\11\data”`

It would be wise to make a backup before doing the upgrade. The Postgresql 11 instance must be running. Then to copy the globals do

`pg_dumpall -U postgres -g -f d:\bakup\postgresql\11\globals.sql`

and then for each database

`pg_dump -U postgres -Fc <database> >  d:\backup\postgresql\11\<database>.fc`

or

`pg_dump -U postgres -Fc -d <database> -f d:\backup\postgresql\11\<database>.fc`

If not already done install Postgresql 12 (as Postgresql 11 is also installed this will be on port 5433)

Then to do the upgrade as follows:

1) Stop Postgresql 11 service (see above)

2)  Edit the `postgresql.conf` file in `d:\postgresql\12\data` and change `port = 5433` to `port = 5432`

3) Edit the windows user environment path (`windows start` then type `env`) to point to Postgresql 12 instead of Postresql 11

4)  Run upgrade by entering the following command.

```
pg_upgrade `
-b “c:\program files\postgresql\11\bin” `
-B “c:\program files\postgresql\12\bin” `
-d “d:\postgresql\11\data” `
-D “d:\postgresql\12\data” --username=postgres
```

(In powershell use backtick (or backquote) ` to continue the command on the next line)

5)  and finally start the new Postgresql 12 service

`pg_ctl start -D “d:\postgresql\12\data”`

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to do a combination of these two resources:

https://gist.github.com/tamoyal/2ea1fcdf99c819b4e07d

and

http://www.gab.lc/articles/migration_postgresql_9-3_to_9-4

The **second** one **helped more** then the first one. Also to not, don't follow the steps as is as some are not necessary.
Also, if you are not being able to backup the data via postgres console, you can use alternative approach, and backup it with pgAdmin 3 or some other program, like I did in my case.

Also, the link: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/serverguide/postgresql.html
Helped to set the encrypted password and set md5 for authenticating the postgres user.

After all is done, to check the postgres `server` version run in terminal:

```
sudo -u postgres psql postgres
```

After entering the password run in postgres terminal:

```
SHOW SERVER_VERSION;
```

It will output something like:

```
 server_version 
----------------
 9.4.5
```

For setting and starting postgres I have used command:

```
> sudo bash # root
> su postgres # postgres

> /etc/init.d/postgresql start
> /etc/init.d/postgresql stop
```

And then for restoring database from a file:

```
> psql -f /home/ubuntu_username/Backup_93.sql postgres
```

Or if doesn't work try with this one:

```
> pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U postgres -d name_of_database ~/your_file.dump
```

And if you are using Rails do a `bundle exec rake db:migrate` after pulling the code :)

Answer (score 0):

For Mac via homebrew:

`brew tap petere/postgresql`,

`brew install <formula>` (eg: `brew install petere/postgresql/postgresql-9.6`)

Remove old Postgres:

`brew unlink postgresql`

`brew link -f postgresql-9.6`

If any error happen, don't forget to read and follow brew instruction in each step.

Check this out for more: https://github.com/petere/homebrew-postgresql

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10 since I had npm, I installed rimraf package. `npm install rimraf -g`

Backup all your databases one by one using command `pg_dump -U $username --format=c --file=$mydatabase.sqlc $dbname`

Then Installed Latest PostgreSQL Version i.e. 11.2 which prompted me to use port 5433 this time.

Followed by Uninstall of older versions of PostgreSQL mine was 10. Note the uninstaller may give a warning of not deleting folder `C:\PostgreSQL\10\data`. That's why we have the next step using rimraf to permanently delete the folder and it's sub-folders.

change into PostgreSQL install directory and ran the command `rimraf 10`. 10 is a directory name. Note use your older version of PostgreSQL i.e. 9.5 or something.

Now add `C:\PostgreSQL\pg11\bin, C:\PostgreSQL\pg11\lib` into the Windows environmental variables. Note my new installed version is 11 thus why I am using `pg11`.

Navigate to `C:\PostgreSQL\data\pg11` then open `postgresql.conf` edit `port = 5433` to `port = 5432`

That's it. Open cmd and type `psql -U postgres`

You can now restore all your backed databases one by one using the command `pg_restore -U $username --dbname=$databasename $filename`

Answer (score -1):

I think this is best link for your solution to update postgres to 9.6

```
https://sandymadaan.wordpress.com/2017/02/21/upgrade-postgresql9-3-9-6-in-ubuntu-retaining-the-databases/
```