# PostgreSQL: Upgrade Postgres Server

Tags: postgresql

How can I upgrade my PostgreSQL server?
I've installed the latest client version with homebrew.

`$ psql (9.6.1, server 9.5.4)` My server is in 9.5.4 version.

How can I upgrade it to 9.6 ?

OS: MacOS

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27624397/3270427

Comment: The example is a little bit complicated. I'll post now the good answer.
Anyway thanks for your comment @mcNets

Comment: usually you can upgrade a minor version by simply copying new binaries

Comment: https://www.packtpub.com/big-data-and-business-intelligence/postgresql-data-architects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer to my question.

For the first we should uninstall posrgresql

`$ brew uninstall postgresql`

Then we should remove db files

`$ rm -rf /usr/local/var/postgres`

After that we should remove Cellar data

`$ rm -rf /usr/local/Cellar/postgresql`

And after removing all files we can start to install new version

`$ brew install postgresql`

If service will not run automatically we can start it just typing the following

`$ brew services start postgresql`

That's all !