# Postgres 9.3 could not connect to server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, osx-mavericks, homebrew, postgresql-9.3

Running into the a similar issue as that mentioned here 
 [Postgres could not connect to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410686/postgres-could-not-connect-to-server)

I am trying to run rake db:create on a rails 4.1.4 project. I have tried everything mentioned in the previous post - any other suggestions are welcome.

Furthermore, after reinstalling postgres, I ran the command
`brew info postgresql` and got this `Conflicts with: postgres-xc` (though I'm not sure if this is relevant). I'm running postgres 9.3.4

Any help will be greatly appreciated...

Thanks!

*Update:* This is the exact error:

`could not connect to server: Socket operation on non-socket
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?`

Things I've tried so far:
`brew uninstall postgresql`
`brew update`
`brew upgrade`
`brew install postgresql`
followed by the list of commands here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/server-start.html

Finally, using the lunchy gem to start postgres worked - http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-postgresql-on-a-mac-with-homebrew-and-lunchy/

Comment: Please always show the exact text of the error message in your question. Also: What connection settings are you using? When you tried "everything" listed in the other posts, what exactly did you do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, using the lunchy gem to start postgres worked - 
http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-postgresql-on-a-mac-with-homebrew-and-lunchy/

Thanks