# Not able to connect with PostgreSQL database with Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I am having an issue while trying to connect with a PG database in my Rails application:

1. I've create my new app with the following command:

   ```
   $ rails new -d postgresql myApp
   ```
2. The application was created successfully. Therefore I proceed with the following command:

   ```
    $ createuser --createdb --login -P myApp
   ```

   The prompt asks me a password for a new role. I enter the password and re-enter it for confirmation. This the message I get after entering the password:

   ```
     createuser: could not connect to database postgres: could not connect to server: 
     No such file or directory
     Is the server running locally and accepting
     connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
   ```

Any help? I am using PG version 9.5.3 and Ruby on Rails version 4.2.4

Comment: `Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket ...` Well, is it? GIYF

Comment: Did you create the database after making the app? Try running "bundle exec rake db:create" to create the database for your app and then try creating a user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Postgres could not connect to server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410686/postgres-could-not-connect-to-server)

Comment: What is the output of "ps auxwww | grep postgres"

Comment: the output is:     "sandropalmieri   2663   0,0  0,0  2432772    468 s000  R+    9:28pm   0:00.00 grep postgres" what does it mean?

Comment: how can I check if the server is running locally?