# Postgres can't connect to server on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: database, postgresql, ubuntu-16.04

I installed postgreSQL using [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-postgresql-with-your-django-application-on-ubuntu-16-04) tutorial, but it can't connect to server.
I use this command to login to Postgres session:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

But I get this error:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I searched in Stackoverflow and found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410686/postgres-could-not-connect-to-server) that says I have to remove *postmaster.bid* file using this command:

```
rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid
```

But it causes an error too:

```
rm: cannot remove '/usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid': No such file or directory
```

These are the *local* directory's contents:

```
bin  etc  games  include  lib  man  n  sbin  share  src
```

So, how can I find the *postmaster.bid* file and remove it? (If it's the solution)

*My OS is Ubuntu 16.04 .*

Answer (score 1):

I faced this same issue on Ubuntu 18.04 and couldn't find a comprehensive answer so I did the following:

- Uninstalled Postgresql completely :

  - ```
    sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql-11 postgresql-client-11 postgresql-client-common postgresql-common postgresql-contrib postgresql-contrib-11
    ```
- Reinstalled using the following commands:

  - ```
    sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list <<END
    deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ bionic-pgdg main
    END
    ```
  - ```
    wget https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc
    ```
  - ```
    sudo apt-key add ACCC4CF8.asc
    ```
  - ```
    sudo apt-get update
    ```
  - ```
    sudo apt-get install postgresql-11
    ```
- Verify that postgresql is backup and running correctly:

  - ```
    sudo service postgresql status
    ```

Now when I run `su -postgresql psql`, the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Check if postgres is completely installed in Ubuntu. If not do it. The do this,

```
rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid
```

This should work. Else reinstall and try.!

Comment: @praveen-c-naik There isn't *var* directory at */usr/local*

Comment: check in the directory which has postgres in terminal and then run it for that directory.