# Error when opening pgAdmin 4 on mac

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I have installed version 4-1.5, but when opening it, it always shows this error "The application server could not be contacted."

Answer (score 43):

I removed the local directory hidden and resolved:

```
$ cd ~
$ rm -r .pgadmin/
```

Note: macOS Sierra (10.12.6) and pgAdmin 4-1.6. Also you are going to loose configuration data like database list tree, et al.

The Databases will remain intact since you are modifying/deleting PgAdmin related data not any of Postgresql itself.

Comment: Perfect! Worked in High Sierra. Caused when I uninstalled postgres 10 and installed 9.6

Comment: Fixes my issue. Happened after I installed pgAdmin 4 v3, then downgraded back to v2.

Comment: Thanks. Fixed for me on High Sierra after upgrading pgAdmin to 4.13

Comment: Also solved my problem with pgAdmin 2.6. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, I fixed it by stopping the service in Postgres app, then start pgAdmin, and then start the Postgres service. I was able to connect it after that. Hope this help.

Comment: You help me! pgAdmin 4.25

Answer (score 1):

I had same error, but in my case I use wrong port number for the database

Answer (score 0):

On my system Safari is the problem as it was default browser.

To fix, make Chrome your default browser and try relaunching pgadmin4

OR

Manually fix by
$ cat ~/.pgAdmin4.5704814747986328352.addr
http://127.0.0.1:62631/?key=0ec25e6a-dfe2-483e-9814-b315ea87c3cf

Paste what *you* get in Chrome

Comment: Worked for me in Safari after ran pgAdmin in Chrome first.