# Fatal Error. application server could not be contacted

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I would like to install PostgreSQL on windows 7. Howver I faced one problem when I am going to launch pgAdmin 4. It shows that "Fatal Error. application server could not be contacted." I tried run as Administrator, deleted file pgAdmin in AppData. Deleted python and in my path. Added PostgreAQL in my path. However due to some reason it shows the above proble. I need your help. Thank you in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pgadmin4 : postgresql application server could not be contacted.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43211296/pgadmin4-postgresql-application-server-could-not-be-contacted)

Comment: I have checked there were not any duplicate. Checked it in systems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unistall existing postgresql on your computer.This should uninstall the entire applications associated with postgresql including pgadmin4. Go to your start menu and type in "pgadmin4" to show if you still have associated file.If you see any,trace the location and delete it.

You can now re-install a fresh copy of POSTGRESQL from [Enterprisedb](https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads)   which will automatically install pgadmin4 for you. The new installation will prompt you to enter new password. Use a password you can remember since you will always need it to access the database.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution that worked for me on windows 10:

1. Delete the pgAdmin folder from AppData C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin (Note: AppData is a hidden folder),
2. Search for "Services" with windows search, scroll down to postgres and click on "stop",
3. Run pgAdmin as Administrator.

Comment: Do not forget to start the postgres service again when pgAdmin is up.

Answer (score -1):

I uninstalled my python IDLE and then installed the latest python IDLE. When installed it will give you an option if you should allow all programs including python to have full access to the AppData PATH choose yes and the fatal error will disappear