# pgAdmin-4 does not open; throws a 'Can't reach this page' error in the browser

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

Disclaimer: I'm answering my own question.
I've just installed Postgres(version does not matter, I checked) and pgAdmin-4;
However, when I try to launch pgAdmin-4, it says 'Can't reach this page'.

I looked it up, tried everything, including pg_hba.conf, pg_dba.conf modifications.

Answer (score 6):

The solution sounds really simple: Change your default browser to Chrome/IE(tried these). It does not open on the MS Edge browser.
I had it as default, since I was working on other html files, and didn't want them to interfere with Chrome tabs that were already open on opening those files.
Wasted a whole day on this, especially none of the signs pointed to a browser issue. Hope you aren't stuck on this!

If this does not work, you might want to look here: [pgadmin4 : postgresql application server could not be contacted.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43211296/pgadmin4-postgresql-application-server-could-not-be-contacted)
[the error message on Edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZLBF.jpg)