# When launch pgAdmin 4 says: The pgAdmin 4 server could not be contacted:

Tags: python, postgresql, pgadmin-4

**tried:**

- run as administrator;
- install as administrator;
- add path C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin to system environment variables;
- remove C:\Users\YourUsernameOrAdmin\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin;
- launch in cmd;
- remove python;
- install old python versions;
- change default port;
- pc and user name Latin;

**when launch pgAdmin 4:**

```
The pgAdmin 4 server could not be contacted:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\web\pgAdmin4.py", line 98, in <module>
    app = create_app()
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin\__init__.py", line 347, in create_app
    if not os.path.exists(SQLITE_PATH) or get_version() == -1:
  File "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin\setup\db_version.py", line 19, in get_version
    return version.value
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'
```

**db_version.py:**

```
from db_upgrade import Version 

def get_version():
    try:
        version = Version.query.filter_by(name='ConfigDB').first()
    except Exception:
        return -1

    return version.value


def set_version(new_version):
    version = Version.query.filter_by(name='ConfigDB').first()
    version.value = new_version
```

> PyCharm says: Cannot find reference 'Version' in 'db_upgrade.py'

**db_upgrade.py:**

```
import os
import flask_migrate

from pgadmin import db


def db_upgrade(app):
    from pgadmin.utils import u_encode, fs_encoding
    with app.app_context():
        flask_migrate.Migrate(app, db)
        migration_folder = os.path.join(
            os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(u_encode(__file__, fs_encoding))),
            os.pardir, os.pardir,
            'migrations'
        )
        flask_migrate.upgrade(migration_folder)
```

Comment: Have you checked similar questions, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43211296/pgadmin4-postgresql-application-server-could-not-be-contacted)

Comment: @m.i.cosacak 
yes, tried:
run as administrator;
install as administrator;
add path C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin to system environment variables;
remove C:\Users\YourUsernameOrAdmin\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin;
launch in cmd;
remove python;
install old python versions;
change default port;
pc and user name Latin;

Comment: Hi @AlexanderEmelyanov,

I was facing the same issue and this answer worked me like a charm. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45823367/7423854