# Query Tool shortcut not working in pgAdmin 4 version 6.2

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I recently updated pgAdmin 4 from version 5.6 to version 6.2. With the update, the query tool shortcut (`alt + shift + q`) no longer works for me. I'm still able to access the query tool from the drop down menu, and other shortcuts like `alt + shift + f` or `alt + shift + h` still work. If I edit the shortcut to something like `alt + ctrl + shift + q` then it works again. Tested on Chrome and Edge with no difference.

Is anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: Yeah, it's an acknowledged bug. At least for you, only the shortcuts are not working, for me I am not even able to create a database.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a few hacks.

Delete contents of folder
`C:\Users\User_Name\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin\sessions`

Stop the service, and run it again as administrator.

And other solutions from this StackOverflow answer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43211296/pgadmin4-postgresql-application-server-could-not-be-contacted)