# Pgadmin logs throws SSL error and "Exception when checking for update "

Tags: python, postgresql, ubuntu, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I am having a tough time getting Pgadmin to work in Windows + WSL +Ubuntu setup.

First I was not able to create a database through their web service, it would just hang, then when I tried to see the log it would not even load up, so I followed the solutions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43211296/pgadmin4-postgresql-application-server-could-not-be-contacted) thread, and solved that one issue.

But now I am getting the following errors, and I have no idea how to approach this.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
pgAdmin Runtime Environment
--------------------------------------------------------
Python Path: "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\python.exe"
Runtime Config File: "C:\Users\srish\AppData\Roaming\pgadmin\runtime_config.json"
pgAdmin Config File: "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\config.py"
Webapp Path: "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgAdmin4.py"
pgAdmin Command: "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\python\python.exe -s C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgAdmin4.py"
Environment: 
  - ALLUSERSPROFILE: C:\ProgramData
...
...
  - windir: C:\WINDOWS
--------------------------------------------------------

2021-12-01 13:39:57,433: WARNING    werkzeug:   WebSocket transport not available. Install simple-websocket for improved performance.

 * Serving Flask app "pgadmin" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production

   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off

Application Server URL: http://127.0.0.1:5431/?key=c1258d56-07d4-4046-a1f2-0f52769030d6
2021-12-01 13:40:00,407: ERROR  pgadmin:    Exception when checking for update
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "urllib\request.py", line 1354, in do_open
  File "http\client.py", line 1252, in request
  File "http\client.py", line 1298, in _send_request
  File "http\client.py", line 1247, in endheaders
  File "http\client.py", line 1007, in _send_output
  File "http\client.py", line 947, in send
  File "http\client.py", line 1421, in connect
  File "ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
  File "ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
  File "ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1131)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\pgAdmin 4\v6\web\pgadmin\browser\__init__.py", line 670, in check_browser_upgrade
    response = urlopen(url, data, 5)
  File "urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
  File "urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
  File "urllib\request.py", line 542, in _open
  File "urllib\request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
  File "urllib\request.py", line 1397, in https_open
  File "urllib\request.py", line 1357, in do_open
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1131)>
```