# Cannot access database through psql after upgrading to 10.3

Tags: postgresql, homebrew, psql

I just upgraded to Postgres 10.3 via Homebrew. I can't seem to login into my databases through "psql [database name]".

I get the following error:

*psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?*

Also, tried running running a restart through HomeBrew ("brew services restart postgresql") with no issues. Below was the output.

Stopping `postgresql`... (might take a while)

==> Successfully stopped `postgresql` (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql)

==> Successfully started `postgresql` (label: homebrew.mxcl.postgresql)

Also ran "ps auxw | grep post" but this didn't yield any output.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the postmaster.pid at the following location /usr/local/var/postgres worked. Also, saw the same answer to the same issue referenced here: [Postgres could not connect to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410686/postgres-could-not-connect-to-server)

Answer (score 0):

Try `rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid`

Then `brew services restart postgresql`