# could not connect to server: Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

this is the massage I'm getting when I try to run the localhost I don't know what's the problem:
could not connect to server: No such file or directory Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
I have uninstall postgresql and reinstall it again but the problem persist

Comment: This is possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410686/postgres-could-not-connect-to-server for mac os and for ubuntu https://askubuntu.com/questions/50621/cannot-connect-to-postgresql-on-port-5432 . If that thread does not solve your issue, you could add additional info about your OS, how did you install postgres etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Postgres could not connect to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410686/postgres-could-not-connect-to-server)