# FATAL: could not open directory "pg_notify": No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, homebrew, macos-big-sur

I am struggling to troubleshoot the startup error for postgres on mac Big Sur.
The symlink exits for `LaunchAgents` as `homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist`

But when I run

```
postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres
```

I get output

```
FATAL:  could not open directory "pg_notify": No such file or directory
LOG:  database system is shut down
```

Does anyone know about a solution for this?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66620279/how-to-get-postgres-to-start-on-big-sur

Comment: Thanks buddy, that did help actually. To anyone else wondering, use the official [postgresapp](https://postgresapp.com/) and save yourself the hassle.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same phenomenon happen to me.
Uninstalling postgresql, deleting the `/usr/local/var/postgres/` directory and reinstalling it solved the problem.

```
$ ls /usr/local/var/postgres/
PG_VERSION              global                  pg_ident.conf           pg_multixact            pg_wal                  postgresql.auto.conf
base                    pg_hba.conf             pg_logical              pg_subtrans             pg_xact                 postgresql.conf
```

```
$ brew uninstall postgresql
$ rm -rf  /usr/local/var/postgres
```

```
$ brew install postgresql
```

```
$ ls /usr/local/var/postgres/
PG_VERSION              pg_commit_ts            pg_ident.conf           pg_notify               pg_snapshots            pg_subtrans             pg_wal                  postgresql.conf
base                    pg_dynshmem             pg_logical              pg_replslot             pg_stat                 pg_tblspc               pg_xact
global                  pg_hba.conf             pg_multixact            pg_serial               pg_stat_tmp             pg_twophase             postgresql.auto.conf
```

Answer (score 4):

I tried almost all of the answers in this question and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410686/postgres-could-not-connect-to-server/75341508#75341508) and these are the steps that finally worked for me to get postgres to start

- tail the logs for postgres.

  - the path needs to be updated depending on where postgres is installed, and your version. I am using postgresql@14 on an m1 Monterey and installed it with homebrew.
  - i finally found the path i needed to look at using [this article.](https://www.notion.so/Postgres-troubleshooting-f5e37772aa2f4176810f678c34cf386f)
  - `tail /opt/homebrew/var/log/postgresql@14.log`

output shows this:

```
2023-02-03 15:33:49.294 CST [82651] FATAL:  could not open directory "pg_notify": No such file or directory
2023-02-03 15:33:49.294 CST [82651] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

- go to the / directory and `cd opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@14`
- create the missing directory (maybe this is a different directory for you)

  - `mkdir pg_notify`
- repeat this process for all missing directories.

  - I needed to mkdir for `pg_tblspc`, `pg_replslot`, `pg_twophase`, `pg_stat_tmp`, `pg_logical/snapshots`, `pg_logical/mappings`, `pg_commit_ts`, `pg_snapshots`, & `pg_commit_ts` but i recommend you specifically run the tail command each time to make sure you are not missing different directories & files than me.

finally after running the tail command repeatedly after creating each missing directory, I got this output.

```
2023-02-03 15:49:18.909 CST [85772] LOG:  redo done at 0/17211D8 system usage: CPU: user: 0.00 s, system: 0.00 s, elapsed: 0.00 s
2023-02-03 15:49:18.914 CST [85771] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

i was then able to create & migrate my db in my project ･ᴗ･

Comment: same for @15, too - thank you very much, it was exactly like you've written!

Answer (score 0):

The solution doing mkdir in /opt/homebrew/var/postgresql@14 works for me!
You must create the following dirs:
pg_tblspc
pg_replslot
pg_twophase
pg_stat
pg_logical/snapshots
pg_logical/mappings/
pg_commit_ts
According to your logs file.. tail -n 10 /opt/homebrew/var/log/postgresql@14.log