# Couldn't create database when migrating to postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I'm trying to deploy on heroku a simple blog I created with RoR for learning purposes and sqlite3 is not supported so I decided to migrate to PostgreSQL.

I changed my database.yml file

```
development:
adapter: postgresql
encoding: utf8
database: blog_development
pool: 5
username: user
password:

test:
adapter: postgresql
encoding: utf8
database: blog_test
pool: 5
username: user
password:
```

installed PostgreSQL using:

```
brew install postgresql
```

removed sqlite3 and added:

```
gem 'pg'
```

and ran bundle install

when I tried running:

```
rake db:create
```

i got:

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I tried fixing it with:

[In Rails, Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql",](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763143/in-rails-couldnt-create-database-for-adapter-postgresql)

and:

http://russbrooks.com/2010/11/25/install-postgresql-9-on-os-x

http://www.mozmorris.com/2011/11/15/configure-postgresql-to-accept-tcpip-connections.html

Addl. Info:

RoR: 4.0

Ruby: 2.0.0

psql: 9.3.1

pg: '0.17.0'

OS: OSX Mavericks

Comment: Is PostgreSQL running? What does `pgrep -lf postgres` return?

Comment: Did you install pgAdmin (http://pgadmin.org/download/macosx.php)?  That can help you make sure your postgres server is setup and running correctly.

Comment: Yes, used lunchy start postgresql

Comment: @KevinSjöberg doesn't return anything

Comment: Then postgres isn't running. Run `pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start` to start it.

Comment: @KevinSjöberg that solved it! have to migrate the db to make sure it works but at least solved this impass. thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure postgres is running

First Install postgres using homebrew(which you've already done)

```
brew install postgresql
```

Second: Create a new PostgreSQL database cluster

```
initdb /usr/local/var/postgres
```

Finally: Start postgresql

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres -l /usr/local/var/postgres/server.log start
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the 'user' user doesn't exist.
On the command line, try this:

```
psql
psql=# create user name_here;
psql=# alter user name_here superuser;
psql=# \q
```