# Unable to create database with rake db:create command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pg

I had postgresql service running but when I run `rake db:create` it abort the rake and throws error

> ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError: connection to server on socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  database “chat_development" does not exist

In my `database.yml` I have

```
development:
  <<: *default
  database: chat_development
```

By running the rake command it should create the database but it didn't. I did a lot research and try out the solutions given but nothing work. I did check on this discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13410686/postgres-could-not-connect-to-server) but when I run `rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid` it throws error

> rm: /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid: No such file or directory

If I run command `ps auxwww | grep postgres` it will show `/opt/homebrew/opt/postgresql/bin/postgres -D /opt/homebrew/var/postgres`

If I remember correctly I had issue with the postgres installation when I was getting started (about 4 weeks ago) and did install using [Postgres.app](https://postgresapp.com), then I had also installed with `brew install postgresql` (since I am using mac). I am not sure if there are conflict due to multiple installation.

But just now I uninstalled postgres.app and also ran `gem uninstall pg` and re-install using command `gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config` (ref [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763143/in-rails-couldnt-create-database-for-adapter-postgresql/19609228#answer-19609228))

The issue is still there. I don't know what to do anymore. Glad if someone can help. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had this issue and never quite figured out why rails was doing this, but below should fix it.

1. in terminal `psql template1`
2. `CREATE USER <username from config/database.yml if specified> with password '<password from config/database.yml if specified>';`
3. `ALTER USER <username ...> WITH SUPERUSER;`
4. `CREATE DATABASE chat_development WITH OWNER = '<username ...>';`
5. `CREATE DATABASE chat_test WITH OWNER = '<username ...>';`

you don't need step 2/3, or the `WITH OWNER = '<username>';` unless you specify a user/password in `config/database.yml`.

Some common mistakes, pay close attention to where I have put single quotes, and don't forget the semi-colons!

Comment: Hi thank you for the solution. I can create the database with these steps.

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this problem, you need progress this in step-by-step fashion.

1. Run the postgresql server
2. Test creating a sample database using a simple client like psql, which should show whether the server is running and you have the right socket/port connection and user credential with authorization
3. Check your application configuration to see if you have the correct connection and user credential setup