# Ruby/Rails not allowing me to CREATE DB using bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
cameronnc@cameron-20fms3pk00]─[~/Desktop/snetwork]
└──╼ $bundle exec rails db:create
Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that /home/cameronnc/Desktop/snetwork/log/development.log exists and is writable (i.e. make it writable for user and group: chmod 0664 /home/cameronnc/Desktop/snetwork/log/development.log). The log level has been raised to WARN and the output directed to STDERR until the problem is fixed.
rails aborted!
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /home/cameronnc/Desktop/snetwork/config/master.key
/home/cameronnc/Desktop/snetwork/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:create => db:load_config => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I am trying to create my db in rails and want to use the latest version of Ruby and rails but I get many many permission errors. I wasn't even allowed to modify my gem files unless I signed in as root. How can I fix this error?

So I ran the following commands BUT I still get an error message of some kind:

```
[✗]─[cameronnc@cameron-20fms3pk00]─[~/Desktop/snetwork]
└──╼ $rails db:create
Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that /home/cameronnc/Desktop/snetwork/log/development.log exists and is writable (i.e. make it writable for user and group: chmod 0664 /home/cameronnc/Desktop/snetwork/log/development.log). The log level has been raised to WARN and the output directed to STDERR until the problem is fixed.
FATAL:  role "cameronnc" does not exist
Couldn't create 'snetwork_development' database. Please check your configuration.
rails aborted!
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: FATAL:  role "cameronnc" does not exist


Caused by:
PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  role "cameronnc" does not exist

Tasks: TOP => db:create
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
┌─[✗]─[cameronnc@cameron-20fms3pk00]─[~/Desktop/snetwork]
└──╼ $sudo su
┌─[root@cameron-20fms3pk00]─[/home/cameronnc/Desktop/snetwork]
└──╼ #sudo -u postgres createuser --superuser cameronnc
┌─[root@cameron-20fms3pk00]─[/home/cameronnc/Desktop/snetwork]
└──╼ #exit
exit
┌─[cameronnc@cameron-20fms3pk00]─[~/Desktop/snetwork]
└──╼ $bundle exec rails db:create
Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that /home/cameronnc/Desktop/snetwork/log/development.log exists and is writable (i.e. make it writable for user and group: chmod 0664 /home/cameronnc/Desktop/snetwork/log/development.log). The log level has been raised to WARN and the output directed to STDERR until the problem is fixed.
   (866.0ms)  CREATE DATABASE "snetwork_development" ENCODING = 'unicode'
Created database 'snetwork_development'
   (684.0ms)  CREATE DATABASE "snetwork_test" ENCODING = 'unicode'
Created database 'snetwork_test'
```

Why am I receiving a:

> $bundle exec rails db:create Rails Error: Unable to access log file.
> Please ensure that
> /home/cameronnc/Desktop/snetwork/log/development.log exists and is
> writable (i.e. make it writable for user and group: chmod 0664
> /home/cameronnc/Desktop/snetwork/log/development.log). The log level
> has been raised to WARN and the output directed to STDERR until the
> problem is fixed.

What is going on and how can I address such an odd error?

Comment: You need to create a user in your postgresql database that matches your login. https://ubiq.co/database-blog/create-user-postgresql/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71996907/12817385 before posting make sure to search stack overflow first

Answer (score 1):

I see two errors:

### Error 1: File permissions

> Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that /home/cameronnc/Desktop/snetwork/log/development.log exists and is writable (i.e. make it writable for user and group: chmod 0664 /home/cameronnc/Desktop/snetwork/log/development.log). The log level has been raised to WARN and the output directed to STDERR until the problem is fixed.

You can try to fix the permissions with `chown` and `chmod`. If you're not familiar with these tools, this is a good opportunity to learn.

If you don't have time to learn to use `chown` and `chmod`, you can delete your application (`~/Desktop/snetwork`) and start again running `rails new` as yourself.

### Error 2: Invalid database configuration

> FATAL:  role "cameronnc" does not exist
> Couldn't create 'snetwork_development' database. Please check your configuration.
> rails aborted!
> ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished: FATAL:  role "cameronnc" does not exist

You can either fix your database configuration (`config/database.yml`) by specifying a valid username, or you can create a `cameronnc` user. Read the postgres manual for details on user mgmt.